# F# IDE scripting support for accessing internal types in referenced assemblies

Tags: f#, f#-interactive

Usually for non-scripting C#/F# project, one can specify a `InternalsVisibleTo` attribute in the dependency assembly and be able to get intellisense for its internal types in the IDE. But in F# scripting, how would I configure the dependency assembly with respect to the IDE I'm using in order to get intellisense for internal types? Of course in order for the script to run by `fsi` I assume I'd need something like

```
[assembly:InternalsVisibleTo("fsi")]
```

But in order to get the IDE support should I also specify every known IDE in the dependency assembly? That doesn't seem to scale very well.

I did a code search and found [this](https://github.com/fsharp/FSharp.Compiler.Service/blob/master/src/assemblyinfo/assemblyinfo.FSharp.Compiler.Service.dll.fs#L22) where `fsc`, `fsi`, compiler service assembly, and their strong name versions, etc. are all specified, seemingly to accommodate IDEs. This is exactly what concerns me and I don't want to litter my assemblies with these. Is there a better way?

Comment: I'm not sure how to solve your problem sorry, but isn't this kind of contrary to the `internal` keyword - if you want to access the types and functions from a script, shouldn't they be marked `public`? Intellisense works in `.fsx` files in Visual Studio already so long as you've referenced the assembly by `#r /path/to/assembly.dll`.

Comment: @JakeLishman there're a lot of reasons for types to be marked internal and in many cases I cannot control that. But I do need to access them for scripting, prototyping, and testing scenarios. Isn't that also one of the points of using `FSI` :) ? I could of course spin up a full blown F# project, properly configure `InternalsVisibleTo`. That defeats the purpose of convenience.

Comment: That's a good point - I'm interested in the solution to this too, then :-)

Comment: The dynamic assembly used by fsi is called `FSI-ASSEMBLY`, but even by using this in the InternalsVisibleTo, it seems the type checker does not see that the internals should be visible. To me this looks like a bug; it might be worth posting on https://github.com/microsoft/visualfsharp/issues.